# Jquery UI drop event plain/text between text in Div contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm sorry for my bad English but I try to make the question understandable.

In the **snippet** (Or the **jsfiddle**) We can find **two draggable** items:

1. foo (If you drag it and drop in the **Div content editable** the [% foo %] text appear where we drop **it between the text**)
2. foo2 (This have the **Jquery UI drag style** (it follows the cursor))

I want to achieve the functionalitty of foo With jquery UI style. But when I try : `event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "[%" + event.srcElement.innerHTML + "%]");` It looks like event is not define if I try to define the function like this:

```
drag: function(ui, event)
```

The motion of the foo2 **Stop work** (It mean is a **error** in the code)

Here is the snippet:

```js
//$( "#foo2" ).draggable();
$( "#foo2" ).draggable({
      start: function(ui) {

      event.preventDefault();
      },
      drag: function(ui) {

      },
      stop: function(ui) {

      }
    });


var btn = document.getElementById("foo");
btn.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
};

btn.ondragstart = function(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "[%" + event.srcElement.innerHTML + "%]");
};
```

```html
<span draggable="true" id="foo" class="btn btn-primary">Foo</span>
<div style="background:red" contenteditable="true" >Put foo between this and this</div>
<a  id="foo2" class="btn btn-primary">Foo2</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The same demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fbprfj5c/1/

Thanks for all your help, recommendations or tips :)

**Update**:

In response to Gaetano:
I like your idea, and is my fault for no tell all the details. You get the main idea but the tricky way of get the the Width of character and calculate the position with that i can do a similar function to achieve the same effect with a more larger div (in the y axis). But in the div can be more elements than characters. I"ll start with your idea, But i think is a shame open another question for this. In another hand you resolve the problem But that "hacky"/simulation to get the caret position i try to improve (I try before without achieve it), So let"s wait a little is someone have an idea

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) for the div element and connect your foo2 draggable element to the droppable.

```js
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').droppable({
    drop: function( e, ui ) { // 6.413793103448276
        var charWidth = getCharWidth(this);
        var position = Math.round(ui.offset.left / charWidth);
        position = (position - 1 >= 0) ? position - 1 : position;
        $(this).text(function(idx, txt) {
            return txt.substr(0, position) + "[%" + ui.draggable.text() + "%]" + txt.substr(position + 1);
        })
    }
});
$( "#foo2" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: 'div[contenteditable="true"]',
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
});


var btn = document.getElementById("foo");
btn.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};

btn.ondragstart = function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "[%" + event.srcElement.innerHTML + "%]");
};



function getCharWidth(ele) {
    var f = window.getComputedStyle(ele)['font'],
            o = $('<div>' + ele.textContent + '</div>')
                    .css({'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'font': f})
                    .appendTo($('body')),
            w = o.width() / ele.textContent.length;
    o.remove();
    return w;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<span draggable="true" id="foo" class="btn btn-primary">Foo</span>
<div style="background:red" contenteditable="true" >Put foo between this and this</div>
<a  id="foo2" class="btn btn-primary">Foo2</a>
```

Comment: I like your idea, and is my fault for no tell all the details. You get the main idea but the tricky way of get the the Width of character and calculate the position with that i can do a similar function to achieve the same effect with a more larger div (in the y axis). But in the div can be more elements than characters. I"ll start with your idea, But i think is a shame open another question for this. In another hand you resolve the problem But that "hacky"/simulation to get the caret position i try to improve (I try before without achieve it), So let"s wait a little is someone have an idea

Comment: But your main idea is a great base and is USEFULL, thanks a lot. You deserve the correct answer but lets wait (or if i find the answer before) if someone can help me with the rest part

Comment: @user3657540 Doesn't a matter. Thank you very much.